Is it "frowned upon" to ask a lot of questions and not answer other people's questions?
I guess my question doesn't get much more complicated than this: Is it "frowned upon" to ask a lot of questions and not answer other people's questions?

Not at all. Not everyone knows enough to be able to answer other people's questions so its perfectly fine to not answer any questions. Of course if you can answer questions, then that's great, but if you don't know the answer, then it's fine to not answer.
If you do have a lot of questions though, you should first see if someone else has asked the same question before you make a new question.

Absolutely agree
